# How to remove only item of array?

Tags: php

I have an array.

```
$a_input = array(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I want to remove 1 from array . out put is :

```
array(2,3,4,5);
```

remove 2 => output:

```
array(1,3,4,5);
```

remove 3 => output :

```
array(1,2,4,5);
```

.....
how to do this with for loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$a_input = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$cnt=count($a_input);
for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++){
   $remove = array($i+1);
   $output1=array_diff($a_input,$remove);
   var_dump("<pre>",$output1);
}
```

[Online test](https://ideone.com/S0Uou0)

Comment: Sorry, my expected is : from array(1,2,3,4,5) . I want to  have 5 array  (2,3,4,5), (1,3,4,5) , (1,2,4,5),(1,2,3,5), (1,2,3,4)

Comment: test this https://ideone.com/S0Uou0

Comment: it work fine for me, thank your support :)

Comment: if this answer is correct please accept it

Answer (score 0):

use `unset`.

```
foreach($a_input as $key => $val){
   if($a_input[$key]==1) unset($a_input[$key]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5);
if (($key = array_search('1', $array)) !== false) {
unset($array[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we are `searching a value` in the array If it is present, then proceed to `get the key` at which required value is present, then `unseting that value`.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/778754)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$a_input = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$numberToSearch=2;

if(in_array($numberToSearch,$a_input))//checking whether value is present in array or not.
{
    $key=array_search($numberToSearch, $a_input);//getting the value of key.
    unset($a_input[$key]);//unsetting the value
}
print_r($a_input);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is **[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)**:

```
$input = array(1,2,3,4,5)
$remove = 1;
$result = array_filter($input, function ($val) use ($remove) {
  return $val !== $remove;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [array_diff](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_diff.asp).

```
$a_input = array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

you can create new array with values like below:

```
$remove = array(1,2);

$result=array_diff($a_input,$remove);
```

output:

```
array(3,4,5);
```

Most of the programmer use this way only.And this will work for multiple elements also.